# Extracting subset of data from multilevel XML when variables have the same name

Tags: python, xml, pandas, elementtree

I have a large amount of xml data which looks like this (only a fraction of data shown):

```
<weatherdata xmlns:xsi="http://www.website.com" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="www.website.com" created="2020-07-06T14:53:48Z">
  <meta>
    <model name="xxxxxx" termin="2020-07-06T06:00:00Z" runended="2020-07-06T09:48:31Z" nextrun="2020-07-06T16:00:00Z" from="2020-07-06T15:00:00Z" to="2020-07-08T12:00:00Z"/>
    <model name="xxxxxx" termin="2020-07-06T00:00:00Z" runended="2020-07-06T09:48:31Z" nextrun="2020-07-06T18:00:00Z" from="2020-07-08T13:00:00Z" to="2020-07-09T18:00:00Z"/>
    <model name="xxxxxx" termin="2020-07-06T00:00:00Z" runended="2020-07-06T09:48:31Z" nextrun="2020-07-06T18:00:00Z" from="2020-07-09T21:00:00Z" to="2020-07-12T00:00:00Z"/>
    <model name="xxxxxx" termin="2020-07-06T00:00:00Z" runended="2020-07-06T09:48:31Z" nextrun="2020-07-06T18:00:00Z" from="2020-07-12T06:00:00Z" to="2020-07-16T00:00:00Z"/>
  </meta>
  <product class="pointData">
    <time datatype="forecast" from="2020-07-06T15:00:00Z" to="2020-07-06T15:00:00Z">
     <location altitude="10" latitude="123" longitude="123">
      <temperature id="TTT" unit="celsius" value="18.8"/>
      <windDirection id="dd" deg="296.5" name="NW"/>
      <windSpeed id="ff" mps="5.8" beaufort="4" name="Laber bris"/>
      <globalRadiation value="524.2" unit="W/m^2"/>
      <humidity value="59.0" unit="percent"/>
      <pressure id="pr" unit="hPa" value="1022.9"/>
      <cloudiness id="NN" percent="22.7"/>
      <lowClouds id="LOW" percent="22.7"/>
      <mediumClouds id="MEDIUM" percent="0.0"/>
      <highClouds id="HIGH" percent="0.0"/>
      <dewpointTemperature id="TD" unit="celsius" value="10.6"/>
     </location>
    </time>
    <time datatype="forecast" from="2020-07-06T14:00:00Z" to="2020-07-06T15:00:00Z">
     <location altitude="10" latitude="123" longitude="123">
      <precipitation unit="mm" value="0.0" minvalue="0.0" maxvalue="0.0" probability="2.0"/>
      <symbol id="LightCloud" number="2"/>
     </location>
    </time>
    <time datatype="forecast" from="2020-07-06T16:00:00Z" to="2020-07-06T16:00:00Z">
     <location altitude="10" latitude="123" longitude="123">
      <temperature id="TTT" unit="celsius" value="19.4"/>
      <windDirection id="dd" deg="291.6" name="W"/>
      <windSpeed id="ff" mps="6.3" beaufort="4" name="Laber bris"/>
      <globalRadiation value="645.3" unit="W/m^2"/>
      <humidity value="55.7" unit="percent"/>
      <pressure id="pr" unit="hPa" value="1022.8"/>
      <cloudiness id="NN" percent="47.5"/>
      <lowClouds id="LOW" percent="47.5"/>
      <mediumClouds id="MEDIUM" percent="0.0"/>
      <highClouds id="HIGH" percent="0.1"/>
      <dewpointTemperature id="TD" unit="celsius" value="10.3"/>
     </location>
    </time>
    <time datatype="forecast" from="2020-07-06T15:00:00Z" to="2020-07-06T16:00:00Z">
     <location altitude="10" latitude="123" longitude="123">
      <precipitation unit="mm" value="0.0" minvalue="0.0" maxvalue="0.0" probability="2.2"/>
      <symbol id="PartlyCloud" number="3"/>
     </location>
    </time>
```

I want to extract the environmental data and place it in a pandas dataframe. I can do this using the following method:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

tree = et.parse(data.xml) #load in the data
root = tree.getroot() # get the element tree root

celsius = []
for x in root.iter('temperature'):
    value = x.attrib.get('value')
    celsius.append(value)

tempdf = pd.DataFrame(celsius,columns=['Temperature (C)'])        
tempdf
```

This gives me the following dataframe with 114 columns:

[image]

I can then repeat this for all the other interesting variables, and use `pd.concat` to join them together. The problem is that there are two 'time' variables for each of the 114 blocks of data, as 'precipitation' has a separate timestamp. When I try to parse the time data like so:

```
time = []
for x in root.iter('time'):
    value = x.attrib.get('to')
    time.append(value)

timedf = pd.DataFrame(time,columns=['Date & Time'])        
timedf
```

This gives double the amount of rows of data (228 instead of 114):

[image]

I can't join the time dataframe together with the others as there are double the amount of time rows than other variables. I would like to only select the first time variable from each of the 114 instances i.e. I want to keep `time datatype="forecast" from="2020-07-06T15:00:00Z" to="2020-07-06T15:00:00Z"` and skip the second one which is for precipitation `time datatype="forecast" from="2020-07-06T14:00:00Z" to="2020-07-06T15:00:00Z"`. I have tried:

```
time = []
for x in root.iter('time')[0]:
    value = x.attrib.get('to')
    time.append(value)
```

But this doesn't work and I am not sure how I can do this when the variable names are identical within each hour of data. I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Comment: your xml is not well formed. Kindly fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider separately building a `temperature` data frame and `precipitation` data frame with `concat` and then `merge` concatenated versions together by common values in `time` and `location` nodes. And consider binding *all* attribute values together using list/dict comprehension.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

tree = et.parse('Input.xml')     # load in the data
root = tree.getroot()            # get the element tree root

temp_list = []; precip_list = []

for n, x in enumerate(root.iter('time')):
    # GET LIST OF DICTIONARIES OF ALL ATTRIBUTES
    x_list = [{i.tag+'_'+k:v for k,v in i.attrib.items()} for i in x.iter('*')] 

    # COMBINE INTO SINGLE DICTIONARY    
    x_dict = {k:v for d in x_list for k,v in d.items()}

    # BUILD DATA FRAME
    df = pd.DataFrame(x_dict, index=[0])
    
    # SEPARATELY SAVE TO LIST OF DATA FRAMES
    if 'temperature_unit' in df.columns: temp_list.append(df)
    if 'precipitation_unit' in df.columns: precip_list.append(df)
    

# MERGE CONCATENATED SETS BY COMMON VARS
df = pd.merge(pd.concat(temp_list),
              pd.concat(precip_list),
              on=['time_to', 'time_datatype',
                  'location_altitude', 'location_latitude',
                  'location_longitude'],
              suffixes=['_t','_p'])
```

Comment: Wow - this goes above and beyond what I asked for, it is an elegant solution I would never have thought of. Beautifully concise - thank you so much for taking the time to help.

Comment: Haha...no problem! Glad to help on your interesting question!